# How to install Visual Basic in Visual Studio ultimate 2012?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, installation

OS: Windows 8.
I have VS2012 Ultimate with only Visual C++ in it. I can't create a Visual Basic project with it. Did installation go wrong? Does VB come with it? If not, how to add Visual Basic into it?

Comment: Run the installer again, tell it you want to add/modify installed components, then pick VisualBasic.NET from the list, and let it install it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run the installer again or go to `Control Panel > Programs > Programs and Features`, find Visual Studio 2012, press Change and select Visual Basic from the install options when prompted.

**Edit**: It should ask you on first run which language you want as your default. To reset this you'll need to:

1. Open Visual Studio
2. Go to `Tools > Import and Export Settings` from the menus,
3. Select the option to reset all settings, press Next,
4. Select `Visual Basic Development Settings` when prompted to select a default collection of settings.

This will set Visual Basic to your default language.

Comment: I ran the installer again and I got only these options: [link](http://tinypic.com/r/2rnblvn/5)

Comment: @AmanSingh Leave the options as default, and on first run it should ask you to specify which language you want as your default. Alternatively, run Visual Studio, go to `Tools > Import and Export Settings`, select the option to reset all settings and then select `Visual Basic Development Settings` when prompted to select a default. Answer updated.