# Visual Studio 2015 custom install does not include Visual Basic?

Tags: installation, visual-studio-2015

There is no option to install the *Visual Basic* language when choosing "custom" install of Visual Studio 2015. I really need to do a custom install, but I also really need Visual Basic!

What a ridiculous fail by Microsoft, unless I'm missing something obvious here?

[image: Visual Studio 2015 custom install no VB]

Comment: check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18755263/how-to-install-visual-basic-in-visual-studio-ultimate-2012) may help you.

Comment: @pRaNaY Thanks but that didn't help (your link is relevant to version 2012 only).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> "A Custom installation automatically includes the components that are in a Default installation."

So as per following, C# and VB always get installed.
[MSDN Guide on Installing VS 2015](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e2h7fzkw.aspx)

Comment: Nice!  Looks like the documentation has been updated since I installed VS 2015 in January (it didn't say that then).

Answer (score 3):

You misinterpret what you see, support for VB.NET and C# is **always** installed.  There is no option to *not* install them.

Not 100% sure why they are not optional but high odds that if it were then the diskspace savings would not be substantial enough.  Lots of the plumbing is already provided by the .NET Framework and MSBuild, they always need to be installed since VS itself depends on them.  The only thing that could be skipped are the language services and the project templates, saves but a few handful of megabytes.

---

Trying to channel why you would ask such a question and not simply let it rip, if you discover that after installation you do not have VB.NET support then the install did not go well.  That's a pretty common problem, almost always caused by having a beta or trial version installed previously and not uninstalling it correctly.  That is a difficult problem to recover from, there is a lot of junk in the registry that should be reset/deleted.  The *usual* way to recover is to run the original installer from the command-line with the `/uninstall /force` options.

Comment: Over the last couple of months I've asked a few people how *they* interpret the VS 2015 custom install UI. Every single person reacted the same way: "Where's Visual Basic?" When I explained that Visual Basic is installed by default, the reaction was unanimous: "That's terrible UI design, it should say so right there!".  So there we have it, I'm certainly not alone in my misinterpretation here.

Comment: It has never once been an option in the past 20+ years.  Oddly nobody ever complained about it until VS2015.  Why you would complain to me about it instead of Microsoft is another thing I'll never understand.  Nothing to do with UI of course, it is the installer that does not have the feature.  Big changes coming in vnext.

Comment: I'm not sure you understand what I mean. Here's a screenshot of the VS 2010 custom install UI: http://i251.photobucket.com/albums/gg313/ramesh_windows/VS/2010/installation_b1/sshot-5.png. All available languages are listed.

Comment: Here is an example of an installer that explicitly shows required components so that users *can be sure* of what's being installed: http://wpdean.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/XAMPP-Components.jpg. I'm not complaining to you, just making an observation in response to your observation. Don't forget that an installer *is* a UI and, as with any UI, it can be well designed or not. The VS2015 installer is *not* well designed and I wouldn't be surprised if later versions improve on it. I let MS know about this in January and they have, at least, updated the installation documentation to clarify.