# Remove Visual Basic from VS2015 Community installation

Tags: visual-studio-2015

The VS2015 installer allows you to skip installing some programming languages, such as C++, F# and Python Tools, but I don't see a checkbox for Visual Basic:

[image]

I only intend to use C#, and my SSD has limited space so I'd rather uninstall it.

Is there any way at all to do that?

Comment: Apparently [you can't](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34739274/4944425), that is not a [custom component](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e2h7fzkw.aspx)...

Comment: Programmers ought to appreciate the complexity of O(n!).  Where n is the number of checkboxes in the installer.  With n = 10, there are 3.6 million possible installs that Microsoft has to test, an impossible task.  It is only practical when the component is isolated well and has few interactions with other ones, like C++ and Python.  Savings are pretty low anyway for VB.NET, most of the plumbing it uses is needed for C# as well.  The Community edition just isn't as free as everybody likes it to be, the Express edition was meant for quick downloads and smaller installs.

Comment: @HansPassant I didn't mean my question as a criticism of Microsoft. Unrelated, but the guy from the other question was downvoted (but I upvoted him) for asking why VB.NET is not available, but IMO they should have placed a disabled checkbox to indicate that it's non-optional. I myself spent 10-20 minutes searching why C# is not available as a checkbox.